# Console server under OpenBSD self-made

Tags: ssh, console, openbsd

How do I configure a console server under OpenBSD. **Want to access via ssh on the console server to access the serial port from everywhere in the world.** Want to use only OpenBSD, so the console server should run under OpenBSD. Thank you very much

Answer (score -1, accepted):

http://openports.se/comms/conserver should provide the funtionality you need.
SSH to host and access the serial lines.

Description:
This program provides a convenient way to manage many remote serial
consoles for machines. A server (conserver(1)) runs on each server
machine and it connects to the specified serial port. It can log,
provide shared access to remote consoles, etc

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand the question very well, but you can simply connect via SSH and then use the built-in serial terminal emulator, cu(1), to access the serial port.  See the man page for details.

Comment: Hi I found this article in German http://www.nwlab.net/tutorials/ser2net/konsolenserver-linux.html I want no commercial console server but OpenBSD as console server. https://www.lantronix.com/products/lantronix-slc-8000/?_ga=1.161595967.220780314.1475130935 For the IT infrastructure in the data center.